# How to apply any mask.png on a video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, mask

I am adding a 1.mp4 on a video 2.mp4, and i want to add a mask on overlay video(1.mp4)

[image: mask.png]

I want to apply this mask on 1.mp4 
I'm using chrome key right now

```
    ffmpeg -t 5 -r 30 -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=640x360
    -i 1.mp4
    -i mask2.png
    -i 2.mp4
    -filter_complex "
    [1:v]scale=500x281[v1];
    [2]scale=500x281[mask];
    [v1][mask]overlay, chromakey=0x00FF00:0.25:0.08 [v2];
    [3:v]scale=640x360[v3];
    [0][v3]overlay [out1];
    [out1][v2]overlay=0:0"
    -y output.mp4
```

[image: output]

But it also removes color from videos.
I'm not sure but i think it can be done by negate
also i don't need audio command, i already done that part
Thanks

Comment: Instead of `chromakey`, I'd `alphamerge` a negative of `[mask]` (well, `alphaextract`ed version of it maybe). This way, you aren't depending on the color for the final overlay.

Comment: I was able to do this by `alphamerge` and `alphaextract`. `[2]alphaextract[mask];
[1:v][mask]alphamerge, scale=500x281 [v2];`. Thanks for your help @kesh

Comment: It might be beneficial for the question to include the images directly and not link to external sites